# Is there a word for a children's pool that's not inflatable?

Tags: terminology

Looking for a word that describes a children's pool, meaning a fixed pool with a shallow water. Not talking about the inflatable kiddie pools from Walmart.

Comment: You mean, eg, the relatively stiff plastic things maybe 4-5 feet in diameter, with a stiff "wall" 8-10 inches high?  I don't recall a term other than "wading pool".

Comment: https://www.toysrus.com/buy/baby-kiddie-pools/sizzlin-cool-36-inch-blue-wading-pool-5f63cf6-87953486

Comment: @HotLicks Didn't even know those exist. Was thinking more about a public swimming pool that has a separate pool with more shallow water, but otherwise the same features as the "adult pool". Something you'd typically find in water parks/playgrounds

Comment: I doubt there is any word. In American English we can say kiddie pool, or just kids pool.  It doesn't necessarily refer to a blow up pool.  My local pool had three areas, a continuous fountain with water only about 1 inch deep (for very young children), a shallow pool of about 3-4 feet high, and a traditional pool that ranged from 4ft to 12ft.  There were no official names for each pool, but colloquially we called it the kiddie pool, the shallow end/shallow side, and the deep end/deep side.

Comment: @KumaAra - "Kids pool" would work for me in British English too. Although I don't think it differentiates between a very shallow pool for paddling and a shallow pool for swimming.

Comment: Even if it's a concrete pool, it's still a "wading pool".